# How to get selected values of product custom options?

Tags: magento-1.9, product, custom-options

I have a virtual product and it consists with various types of custom options such as drop-downs, text fields, radio buttons etc. Once the place order clicks I'm firing an event observer. There I want to get the selected values of all these custom options.

How to achieve this? I can get the option titles. But can't get the selected values of them.

Comment: you mean ordered item option values?

Comment: yes, i can get the order item and then the product. But i cannot get the custom option values (selected) of it

Comment: check my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got it solved.

```
public function getProductCustomOptionsData($observer)
    {
        $event = $observer->getEvent();
        $order = $event->getOrder();
        foreach ($order->getAllVisibleItems() as $item){

            $optionArray = $item->getProductOptions();
            foreach($optionArray['options'] as $option) {
                $str = $option['label'] . ' : ' . $option['value'];
                 Mage::log($str, null, 'taxi.log', true);               
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: if you think your answer best suits your question, please accept it so as others know it's the right solution :)

Comment: ah yh, forgot about that :)

Answer (score 2):

Try the below code,

```
    $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
    $items = $order->getAllVisibleItems();
    foreach ($items as $item) {
    $options = $item->getProductOptions(); 
    $customOptions = $options['options'];   
    if(!empty($customOptions))
    {
      foreach ($customOptions as $option)
      {     
         $optionTitle = $option['label'];
         $optionId = $option['option_id'];
         $optionType = $option['type'];
         $optionValue = $option['value'];
      }
   }
```